# Prove that $\prod_{a=0}^9 \prod_{b=0}^{100}\prod_{c=0}^{100}(\omega^a + z^b + z^c)$ is an integer congruent to $13\mod 101$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

> Let $\omega= e^{2\pi i/10}, z= e^{2\pi i/101}$. Prove that $\prod_{a=0}^9 \prod_{b=0}^{100}\prod_{c=0}^{100}(\omega^a + z^b + z^c)$ is an integer congruent to $13\mod 101$.

> I'd prefer to avoid using any Galois theory or symmetric sum theory if possible. If symmetric sum theory must be used since it's simply too hard to justify otherwise, a link to some resources that might be useful to learning about this theory would be appreciated.

I'm not sure how to prove the given product is an integer using elementary methods.

Let $p=101,r=10.$ I know things like $\prod_{k\mod p} (x-z^k) = x^p-1$ and $\prod_{k\mod r} (x-\omega^k)=x^r-1$. I also know that for integers u and v, $(u+v)^p \equiv u^p+v^p\mod p$. Does this hold for some complex numbers that aren't integers?

In the product below, $0\leq a < r, 0\leq b,c<p$. To find the remainder modulo p, I'm not sure whether the following starting steps are valid (in particular, why is the congruence valid): $\prod_{a,b,c} (\omega^a + z^b+z^c) = \prod_{a,b} (-1)^p ((-\omega^a - z^b)^p-1) \equiv \prod_{a,b} (\omega^{pa} + z^{pb} - (-1)^p) = \prod_{a,b} (\omega^{pa}+2) = \prod_{a} (\omega^{pa} + 2)^p \mod p.$

From here, one can compute the remainder using Fermat's little theorem and the fact that $\{pa\}_{a=0}^{r-1} = \{a\}_{a=0}^{r-1}$, and the simplified result is $(-1)^{pr} ((-2)^r - 1).$

Comment: This is from 2015 HMMT team, so you can read their solution. Essentially all that is needed is repeated usage of the identities that you stated. The value is $ (-2)^{10} - 1 = 1023 $.